# How to save XML output when using FOR XML clause?

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

So, I'm trying to save my SQL Query result as a XML file. I already, have my Query result outputting the XML I want, but I am eventually going to be using this as a stored procedure so I need to be able to output the results as XML files.

I have tried using the `xp_cmdshell` method...

```
declare @cmd nvarchar(255);

select @cmd = ' bcp " Select
    (
    Select GetDate() AS [ApplicationArea/CreationDateTime], BODID.BODID AS [ApplicationArea/BODID]
    From BODID
    Where BODID = "ME-COIL-MESSAGE"
    For XML Path(''), Type
    ),
    (
    Select 
        (
        Select pp.EquipmentID AS [Location/EquipmentID], pp.EquipmentElementLevel AS [Location/EquipmentElementLevel] , GetDate() AS [PublishedDate]
        From ProductionPerformance AS pp
        For XML Path(''), Root("ProductionPerformance"), Type
        ),
        (
        Select ProductionResponse.ID,
            (
            Select Sample.MaterialLotID AS [ID],
                (
                Select MaterialLotID, ID AS [MaterialActualProperty/ID], ValueString AS [MaterialActualProperty/Value/ValueString] 
                From Sample
                For XML Path(''), Root("MaterialActual") , Type
                )
            From Sample
            Where MaterialLotID is not null 
            For XML Path(''), Root("SegmentResponse"), Type
            )
        From ProductionResponse
        For XML Path(''), Root("ProductionResponse"), Type
        )
    For XML Path(''), Root("DataArea"), Type
    )
For XML Path(''), Root("SyncProductionPerformance"), Type" ' + 'queryout "C:\Users\spakuresa\Documents\Out\sample.xml" -S YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME -T -w -r -t -x';

exec xp_cmdshell @cmd
go
```

the result is this and no file is saved...
[image]

Comment: Just add FROM [table_name] before FOR XML. I would also suggest to do some "Googling" of your own for your homework assignments. A google query like this should give you enough answers: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=.net+implicit+conversion+from+int+to+string&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=sWFXWaDjEs7N8gfCoZPwBQ#q=SQL+Server+export+XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Save the data to an xml file, turn on SQLCMD Mode then add the ':out' parameter to the top of the script.

[image]

[image]

As far as 'passing a table', just add the from clause before 'FOR XML PATH('SyncProductionPerformance')'

Comment: It doesn't out put the way I want it to be all nicely formatted but does work! Thanks!